# Where to place __attribute__ ((aligned)) with typedef:ed struct?

Tags: gcc

I have Googled information on gcc's `__attribute__ ((aligned))` to learn more about how to use the attribute.

According to GNU "You may specify aligned and transparent_union attributes either in a typedef declaration or just past the closing curly brace of a complete enum, struct or union type definition and the packed attribute only past the closing brace of a definition."  In addition the document shows the following example:

```
struct S { short f[3]; } __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
```

But I have found few examples with "typedef struct".  I found the following two:

```
typedef struct __attribute__ ((aligned)) { char a; int x; } foo;
typedef struct { char a; int x; } __attribute__ ((aligned)) foo;
```

Which is the preferred method: attribute after struct and before `{`, or attribute after `}` and before foo?

Do they both deliver the same result?

I would greatly appreciate any additional detail about the correct usage of `__attribute__ ((aligned))` with a typedef:ed struct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [GCC doc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html):

> For an enum, struct or union type, you
>   may specify attributes either between
>   the enum, struct or union tag and the
>   name of the type, or just past the
>   closing curly brace of the definition.
>   **The former syntax is preferred**.